# jQuery - How can I retrieve the value of attribute of an html element? Also, can I use that value as a variable?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html structure like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <span id="myFirstSpan"></span>
    <span id="mySecondSpan"></span>
</div>
```

I'd like to get the value of a specific id and use it as a variable. As now I've come onto this script:

```
<script>
    var myIdValue = jQuery("#myDiv span").attr("id");
</script>
```

The output I want to obtain is `var myIdValue = "myFirstSpan"`.
But I've not been able to retrieve that value.
Am I doing something wrong in the script? Or there's something else I'm missing?

**Edit:**
The typo was only in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your code with DOM ready and change jQUery to jQuery

```
$(function(){
var myIdValue = jQuery("#myDiv span").attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `jQUery`

```
var myIdValue = jQuery("#myDiv span:first").attr("id")
```

or

```
var myIdValue = $("#myDiv span:first").attr("id")
```

Also you can use [:first Selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Comment: there is more than one span

Comment: @A.Wolff, this is not a problem with the getter form of `attr()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ya, for the first span. But its quite confusing IMHO

Comment: @A.Wolff, I have added `:first Selector` hope that's not confusing anymore. thanks @FrédéricHamidi

Answer (score 0):

Typo

it's `jQuery` not `jQUery`

```
var myIdValue = jQuery("#myDiv span").attr("id");
```

or you can use `$`

```
var myIdValue = $("#myDiv span").attr("id");
```

---

And make sure your code is in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Its jQuery not jQUery

```
var myIdValue = $("#myDiv span").attr("id");
alert(myIdValue)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8x2qs/)